# how to find first level of child tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have XML like below

```
<parent id="parent">
    <body>
          body text<body>hello</body>
    </body>
</parent>
```

as shown in above code it have parent tag where there is only body tag should available, but there is some text in body tag with  tag again.
so if i use

```
$('#parent').find('body').text();
```

it show output as

```
body text hello
```

but i want the output exactly like

```
body text<body>hello</body>
```

how should i do? If again there are more than one body tag are written in first body tag it should be treated as only text. not as tag.

Comment: try `$('#parent').find('body').html();`

Comment: @ArunPJohny i want the content of only first child <body> tag

Comment: `$('#parent > body') or $('#parent').children() `

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/esdu9r1n/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html instead:

```
$('#parent').find('> body').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#parent').find('body:first').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <body>and another text followed by <div class="someText"></div>Some text followed by</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
var texts = $('.someText, body').map(function(){
    return this.previousSibling.nodeValue
});
alert(texts[0]); // "Some text followed by "
alert(texts[1]); // " and another text followed by "
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/rj0x8pf2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some DOM Traversing:

```
$('#parent').find('body').first().html();
```